# why custom aside or slide panel not slide using angular strap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am making a slide panel .So I googled it and found angrular stap library .I study that library try to make slide panel .
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##asides .I import all js required for that but my side panel not slide as given on site.I don't know where I am wrong .
Here is my code with plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/GIFyFSdyJI8tHq5nlBBn?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/64qidru3z31h5ns/angular-strap.js"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/meplmw59rwg2dmy/angular-strap.tpl.js?m=d"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8km0nfoc9noz9ns/modal.js?m="></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/40vdgl5hglimwfi/aside.js?m="></script>



</head>

<body class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-template="aside.html" data-placement="left" data-animation="am-slide-left" bs-aside="aside" data-container="body">Custom aside
  <br>
  <small>(using data-template)</small>
</button>
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap','mgcrea.ngStrap.modal', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.aside']);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: any body have idea of this Question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to their documentation:

1) You should include angular-animate module:

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

2) You have to include additional CSS animation styles from AngularMotion project:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgithub.com/mgcrea/angular-motion/master/dist/angular-motion.min.css">
```

3) You also have to include another additional CSS file for asides:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/static/styles/bootstrap-additions.min.css">
```

4) What is not mentioned in documentation - you have to add 'ngAnimate' module to dependencies:

```
  var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

**Plunker example**

http://plnkr.co/edit/WVx7F92xE8XcfeUqwV7l?p=preview

Comment: can you share plunker

Comment: check this it speed it too fast http://plnkr.co/edit/GIFyFSdyJI8tHq5nlBBn?p=preview

Comment: playing with it now, will let you know if I solve the problem

Comment: anser is great..but if you check there is two field in aside.html (edit and delete) it is not display..but till better anser

Comment: I think I choose wrong library because I also see one more issue .it hide when I click inside the panel.but in general all panel close when user click outside not inside

Comment: if you have any idea of these issue please discuss

Comment: For displaying some information in aside you should define some controller for this aside and define its $scope. I've just updated plunker with this code.

Comment: thanks @egor but if you saw there is no panel which  close when user click inside the panel ..it is closing..it is better is it is closing when click outside.

Comment: if you go to http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##asides you will see exactly the same behaviour (click on area of aside with no content closes it) - so looks like this is default behaviour of this module and is not related to the question discussed here. If you want to solve this somehow I suggest to open new issue describing what you want to achieve on https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues. P.S. plunker URL - http://plnkr.co/edit/WVx7F92xE8XcfeUqwV7l?p=preview

Comment: thanks man ..!!! if you have time please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227719/how-to-show-static-data-on-jstree-using-angular-jstree-js-plugin

Comment: @EgorSmirnov the link in #3 is no longer working. Can you please update your answer?